# регулярное выражение для валидации строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, которая содержит емайлы. Если строка содержит хотя бы один не емайл типа gmail.com - строка не валидная.

igoer@gmail.com igoesdr@gmail.com igoer@MAIL.ru igoer@gmail.com sfkjhg@zuzu.com

Я попробовал вот так: ^(.+@gmail.com).*$
но не работает

Comment: Попробуйте `^\s*\S+@\S+(?:\s+\S+@\S+)*\s*$`

Comment: `/(.*@gmail\.com)$/ui`